# Difference between torsion, out of plane, coplanar and perpendicular bends?

Tags: physical-chemistry, molecules, spectroscopy, molecular-structure, ir-spectroscopy

In Infrared spectroscopy, stretches are easily understandable. But, how do I visualize (or conceptually understand) the difference between dihedral (torsions), out of plane bends, coplanar bends, and perpendicular bends? Can you give examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A molecule with N atoms has 3N degrees of freedom

3 translational modes

if it is linear, it will have 2 rotational modes; if non-linear 3

This leaves 3N-6 (3N-5 if linear) vibrational modes.  Vibrational modes are further subdivided into stretching, bending or torsional motions.

- Stretching motions can be symmetric or asymmetric
- Bending motions are often referred to as scissoring, twisting, wagging, and rocking
- Torsional motions refer to rotations about bonds

This diagram illustrates these various stretching and bending vibrations

[image]

Depending on the geometric relationship between the transition moment for a specific vibrational mode and the symmetry axis for the mode, vibrational modes may be further classified as parallel or perpendicular.

Here is a [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170712203950/http://mackenzie.chem.ox.ac.uk/teaching/Molecular%20Vibrational%20Spectroscopy.pdf) to a 31 page article (slide show) that has a lot of background and pictures on this subject. Section 4.11 (page 19) might be particularly interesting to you.

One final example that you might be interested in, formaldehyde has 4 atoms and is non-linear so it will have 6 vibrational modes.  These are all pictured on page 2 in this [link](http://szerves.chem.elte.hu/oktatas/ea/Perczel/IR.pdf).

Comment: The link to the 31-page article is no longer useful (redirects to MacKenzie's academic home page).

Comment: @dat Thanks for pointing that out.  I was able to find a new link to the [full 31 page article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170712203950/http://mackenzie.chem.ox.ac.uk/teaching/Molecular%20Vibrational%20Spectroscopy.pdf) using the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/).